# Different behavior when using Spark REPL and standalone Spark program

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I run this code through Spark REPL :

```
  val sc = new SparkContext("local[4]" , "")

  val x = sc.parallelize(List( ("a" , "b" , 1) , ("a" , "b" , 1) , ("c" , "b" , 1) , ("a" , "d" , 1)))

  val byKey = x.map({case (sessionId,uri,count) => (sessionId,uri)->count})
  val reducedByKey = byKey.reduceByKey(_ + _ , 2)

  val grouped = byKey.groupByKey
  val count = grouped.map{case ((sessionId,uri),count) => ((sessionId),(uri,count.sum))}
  val grouped2 = count.groupByKey
```

The REPL displays the type of grouped2 as :

```
grouped2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Seq[(String, Int)])]
```

However if I use same code within Spark program a different type for grouped2 is returned as shown in this error :

```
type mismatch;
  found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Iterable[(String, Int)])]
  required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Seq[(String, Int)])]
  Note: (String, Iterable[(String, Int)]) >: (String, Seq[(String, Int)]), but class RDD is invariant in type T.
    You may wish to define T as -T instead. (SLS 4.5)
  val grouped2 :  org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Seq[(String, Int)])] = count.groupByKey
```

This is entire code for standalone mode :

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.rdd._

object Tester extends App {

  val sc = new SparkContext("local[4]" , "")

  val x = sc.parallelize(List( ("a" , "b" , 1) , ("a" , "b" , 1) , ("c" , "b" , 1) , ("a" , "d" , 1)))

  val byKey = x.map({case (sessionId,uri,count) => (sessionId,uri)->count})
  val reducedByKey = byKey.reduceByKey(_ + _ , 2)

  val grouped = byKey.groupByKey
  val count = grouped.map{case ((sessionId,uri),count) => ((sessionId),(uri,count.sum))}
  val grouped2 : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Seq[(String, Int)])] = count.groupByKey

}
```

Should the returned types in REPL and Standalone not be equal ?

Update : in Standalone grouped2 is inferred as `RDD[(String, Iterable[Nothing])]` so 
`val grouped2: RDD[(String, Iterable[Nothing])] = count.groupByKey compiles` .

So there are three possible types being returned depending on how program is run ?

Update 2 : IntelliJ seems to inferring the types incorrectly :

```
val x : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (String, Int))] = sc.parallelize(List( ("a" , ("b" , 1)) , ("a" , ("b" , 1))))

val grouped = x.groupByKey()
```

IntelliJ infers `grouped` as `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Iterable[Nothing])]`

When it should be `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Iterable[(String, Int)])]` (which is what Spark REPL version 1.0 infers)

Comment: Is there any chance you're using different versions? The API did change between 0.9 and 1.0.

Comment: @TravisBrown your correct, REPL was 0.9 and I was running same code from 1.0 source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness: the Spark API changed between 0.9 and 1.0 here, and `groupByKey` now returns a pair with an `Iterable` as its second member instead of a `Seq`.

On the IntelliJ issue—it's unfortunately not too hard to confuse IntelliJ's type inference. If it comes up with `Nothing` it's pretty likely to be wrong.